# PWA expected behavior when updating manifest

Tags: google-chrome, progressive-web-apps

I develop a PWA and can't find an exact answer about the expected behavior of the downloaded "app" when the manifest is updated (for example: theme-color).
The question is: should the saved app automatically use the latest manifest on updating? I can see browser (Chrome) updates manifest on refresh. But the saved app doesn't.
I found information from 2018 that it was the normal behavior but later this quote was removed from docs. I can't find the actual information.
Thanks in advance!